# Why isn't my Xamarin.iOS app receiving push notifications from Google Firebase?

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to use  Google Firebase to send push notifs to my Xamarin Forms App for iOS... I'm not receiving the notifications

To send the notifications I'm simply copying the Token out of my output window, putting my app in the background, and pasting the toking into the Firebase notif builder.

I receive the FCM Token so my App is definitely talking to Firebase.

So far I've tried:

- Revoking my apple developer certificates and provisioning profile then making new ones.
- I created A new Firebase project and Included the new GoogleService-Info.plist file (Build action -> BundleResource).. I didn't think that this would do anything
- enabled remote notifications in the background mode of my info.plist

Any suggestions appreciated please!

```
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary 
    options)
    {   

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

        UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();

        Firebase.Core.App.Configure();

        _connection = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDb>().GetConnection();

        LoadApplication(application: new V5KitchenApp.App());



        // Register your app for remote notifications.
        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
        {
            // iOS 10 or later
            var authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound;
            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(authOptions, (granted, error) => {
                Console.WriteLine(granted);
                var token = Messaging.SharedInstance.FcmToken ?? "";
                Console.WriteLine($"FCM token: {token}");
                SendTokenToServer(token);
            });

            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;

            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            Messaging.SharedInstance.Delegate = this;
        }
        else
        {
            // iOS 9 or before
            var allNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
            var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(allNotificationTypes, null);
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
        }

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
```

Here's how I override DidReceiveRemoteNotification

```
    public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(
    UIApplication application,
    NSDictionary userInfo,
    Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
    {
        PresentNotification(userInfo);
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData);
    }
```

And here's how I present the notification

```
    void PresentNotification(NSDictionary dict)
    {
        NSDictionary aps = dict.ObjectForKey(new NSString("aps")) as NSDictionary;
        var msg = string.Empty;
        if (aps.ContainsKey(new NSString("alert")))
        {
            msg = (aps[new NSString("alert")] as NSString).ToString();
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(msg))
        {
            msg = "(unable to parse)";
        }

        MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, App.NotificationReceivedKey, msg);
    }
```

I'm using Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging v3.1.2 Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core v5.1.8 Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.InstanceID v2.0.0

Comment: I'm using Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging v3.1.2
Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core v5.1.8
Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.InstanceID v2.0.0

Comment: Also, Firebase thinks that the message has been sent successfully.

Comment: Have you gone through the official docs to make sure you did not miss some configuration and/or set up? https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/blob/master/Firebase.CloudMessaging/component/GettingStarted.md

Comment: I fixed it... Basically I uninstalled the Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core v5.1.8 Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.InstanceID v2.0.0 nuget packages and everything worked fine! 

I also, didn't need the DidReceiveRemoteNotification method or the PresentNotification method.

Comment: I have the seam problem, connect with firebase and return the token, but when I am test on firebase don't show the notification, I remove packages and install again and the problem persist, anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

The problem are Firebase versions
I used the next versions:

```
Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.InstanceID 2.0
Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging 2.0
Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core 4.0.3
Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Analtics 4.0.2
```